# To print a table coloured according to the elements of the db

Tags: php, html, css, loops, foreach

for a project in HTML,CSS,PHP and JS I have to print the cells of a table according to the elements of a database. For example, if a cell is property of user1@test.com I want that the cell is blue, because in the database the colour for the user1 is blue. I have associated with success the user with the colour in the database, but I'm not able to scan every cells of the table.
In fact, my code is able to colour in blue just one cell of a single user, even if the user1 has more than one prenotation. This is my code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users");
$users=$result->fetch_assoc();
foreach ($users as $result){

        $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM prenotations WHERE username='user1@test.com'");
        $info_prenotations=$result-> fetch_assoc();

        $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM colors WHERE username='user1@test.com'");
        $info_colour=$result-> fetch_assoc();

        $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT username from prenotations where username='user1@test.com'");
        $info_username=$result->fetch_assoc();

}
```

And this is the cose for the table:

```
<table border="0" summary="Week">

            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Mon</th>
                <th>Thur</th>
                <th>Wed</th>
                <th>Tues</th>
                <th>Fri</th>
            </tr>


            <?php for ($i=1; $i<=11; $i++) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <th>Slot <?php echo $i; ?></th>
                    <?php for ($j=1; $j<=5; $j++) { ?>
                        <td style="<?php if (intval($info_prenotations["slot"]) == $i && intval($info_prenotations["day"]) == $j) { echo "background-color: ".$info_colour["colour"].";"; } ?>"></td>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>


        </table>
```

Now I want to use the foreach loop in a way that I can scan the entire table to print the different cells for the different users. I suppose that my error is in the foeach loop, which I don't understand very well. Someone can help me, please?

Comment: I think if you did a little research on the JOIN syntax in SQL you would be able to get all this data in One query and then producing the HTML would be a LOT Simpler

Comment: I forgot to say that in this assignment I cannot use foreign keys, join etc. Yes, I know that this is insane, but these are the rules of the project: I can only use CREATE, ALTER, DROP, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE.

Comment: `JOIN` is a subset of `SELECT` so therefore should be allowed

Comment: Yes I know but the rules say just CREATE, ALTER, DROP, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE so i don't want to risk.